# Formly - how to access controler property from an inline template

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

In the code below  how do I link the `ng-model` property of the input fields to the `this.test` variable.

```
class NewComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.test = 'test';
    this.fields = [
        {
          template:
           '\
             <div class="form-group">\
               <input ng-model="test" type="text" class="form-control">\
             </div>\
            '
         }
    ]
  }
}


angular.module('app')
  .component('NewComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'new.html',
    controller: NewComponent,
    controllerAs: 'New'
  });
```

I tried `$ctrl.test` and `New.test`.... nothing!

Comment: if it is an angular2, please use [(ngModel)] and angular1.5 then $ctrl.test

Comment: It's Angular 1.5. I tried $ctrl but it's not working... I added some code...

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/eeUULQ1YrLhsQvSuA0fD?p=preview

Comment: I obviously know how to link html to my controller. The issue is with the formly template field

Comment: I hope this answers your question : https://plnkr.co/edit/RAraWjtG8Biq0wDK0j5E?p=preview

Comment: @Mika, clearly varit05 didn't provide a useful answer :( I don't think they actually read your question. I'm having the same problem, although a slightly different issue. I am growing to hate Formly as much as I like it.

Comment: hahaha same here. try `ng-model="model.test"` and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

should just be able to do:

```
ng-model="model.test"
```

Stick with it, the more you know the more you'll grow to love it...use it at work all day long, it's pretty phenomenal some of the advanced stuff you can do after a while...